# addEventListener() with "click" can't run but no error show up to shuffle text with Chaffle.js

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with **Chaffle.js** library

I tried with jQuery and pure Javascript to add 1 more event is click to shuffle text when I click on a button with **id="test"** but they can't work and I don't see any errors show up in F12.

I hope you guys can help me.

Here is my code on Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yc8OrVW6QgVt0V6t

```
<html>
  <head>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chaffle@2.1.0/src/chaffle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="test">Shuffle</button>
    <h1 class="shuffle">This created for shuffle effect but it isn't work</h1>
    <h3 data-chaffle="en">About Me</h3>

    <script>
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-chaffle]");
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
        var chaffle = new Chaffle(el);
        el.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
          chaffle.init();
        });
      });

     document.querySelectorAll("#test").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var elm = document.querySelectorAll(".shuffle");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elm, function (el) {
           el.dataset.chaffle ='en'; 
          var chaffle = new Chaffle(el);
          el.addEventListener("click", function () {
            chaffle.init();
          });
        });
      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is maybe a bug in `chaffle.js` line 54

```
if (dataLang.length !== 0) data.lang = dataLang
```

its not check `dataLang` for `null`, so it required to add`data-chaffle` attribute to the element

```
var elm = document.querySelectorAll(".shuffle");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elm, function (el) {
   el.dataset.chaffle ='en'; // <== append this
```

Comment: oh I knew that before, thank you. It only works if I click on the text but I mean when I click on `<button id="test">Shuffle</button>` it will shuffle the text in **h1 tag with class="shuffle"** :( but I can't make it work and I'm looking for help about this.

Comment: if you want to shuffle `h1` on button click, remove the event and call the init `var chaffle = new Chaffle(el);  chaffle.init();` also call `querySelector("#test")` not `querySelectorAll("#test")`